# Execute script when ubuntu 16.04 starts

Tags: 16.04, server, bash, scripts

How can i automate this so it runs when ubuntu starts.

```
cd /otp/keycloak/bin
sudo nohup ./standalone.sh -0.0.0.0 bmanagement 0.0 offset = 100
```

Comment: You can either place that in the .rc file (located in your home/user directory) or, set up a cron job

Comment: @WilliamMartens Please add answers as answers, not comments :)

Comment: @vidarlo HEY! Thanks so much for pointing that out; of course - //Have a nice weekend!